# Android - When is the right time to size and create controls?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Folks,

I am working on a custom view that displays images as a grid:

```
class MyImageGridView extends LinearLayout {
   ....
   public addItem(String imageFileName);
   ...
}
```

From MainActivity's `onCreate` method, I call `addItem` for all the images I need to display.

At some point, I need to create child controls. But first, I need to calculate the width of the control. This width is based proportionately on the width of the parent control. For example, if the width of `MyImageGridView` is 600 and I decided to show 3 images per row, the width of my child control would be set to

```
600/3=200 pixels.
```

The width of the parent control also determines the number of child controls I will eventually have. For each row in the grid, I end up creating another `LinearLayout` control.

I figured I could do all this in `onSizeChanged` event of `MyImageGridView`. However, it appears I cannot really create any child controls in `onSizeChanged`. Eclipse just locks up.

I cannot really create the controls in `onCreate` as the width of the control has not yet been determined and therefore I won't really know how many child controls I will end up creating.

I am wondering if anyone has a better idea on what would be the ideal event to create the controls dynamically.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Why cant you do this in onResume? you are entering a recursive loop when u change things in onSizeChanged

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looks like getWidth() and getHeight() both return 0 on onResume. This won't work.

Comment: Not sure what obj u calling getWidth on but try to override this protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) for your root viewgroup object

Comment: onLayout and onMeasure, I think

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can probably do it during onLayout which will supply dimensions determined from onMeasure. It sounds like you might not need to override onMeasure in your case, so that keeps it simple. You need to be cautious with adding views during [onLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) the android framework provides a few specialised members for doing this.. see [addViewInLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addViewInLayout%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams,%20boolean%29)..